# OpenGL, loading textures - additional noise on textures

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, devil

In our own 3d application I'm loading multiple textures, using devil library. When attempting to load one texture, I'm calling `ilutRenderer( ILUT_OPENGL );`, which in a turn perform following function calls:

```
ILboolean ilutGLInit()
{
    // Use PROXY_TEXTURE_2D with glTexImage2D() to test more accurately...
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, (GLint*)&MaxTexW);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, (GLint*)&MaxTexH);
    if (MaxTexW == 0 || MaxTexH == 0)
        MaxTexW = MaxTexH = 256;  // Trying this because of the VooDoo series of cards...

    // Should we really be setting all this ourselves?  Seems too much like a glu(t) approach...
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_FALSE);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    if (IsExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_texture_compression") &&
        IsExtensionSupported("GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc")) {
            ilGLCompressed2D = (ILGLCOMPRESSEDTEXIMAGE2DARBPROC)
                wglGetProcAddress("glCompressedTexImage2DARB");
    }
#endif

    if (IsExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_texture_cube_map"))
        HasCubemapHardware = IL_TRUE;

    return IL_TRUE;
}
```

`ilutRenderer( ILUT_OPENGL );` needs to be called only once (for each newly created window), but while experimenting I've called same function multiple times. (one call for each loaded texture)

If same function were called multiple times - loaded openGl texture was looking with poorer quality than if called once. (I have multiple textures, but most of them with poorer quality, not sure about first image).

I was stumbled about it - since from my perspective that call did not do anything special - why it cannot tolerate multiple similar calls ?

Well, I've started to filter out which functions can be called multiple times and which cannot be - and concluded that it was `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);` which triggered odd behavior. So wrapping function like this:

```
    if( !bInitDone )
    {
        bInitDone = TRUE;
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }
```

after that `ilutRenderer( ILUT_OPENGL )` can be called as many times as needed.

I have also tried to centralize opengl initialization like this:

```
...
InitGL( OnWindowReady )

...

void OnWindowReady( void )
{
    ilInit();
    ilutRenderer( ILUT_OPENGL );
}

... may be some rendering code ...

void LoadModel( const wchar_t* file )
{
    ... load texture 1 ...
    ... load texture 2 ...
}
```

But textures are still appearing "as corrupted". Maybe window should be rendered at least once before starting to load textures, but I want to know what functions in OpenGL are reflecting texture corruption / looking nice kind of state.

I have "NVidia Quadro K2100M", driver version 375.86.

Is this display driver bug ?
How do you typically report bugs to NVidia ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing (and the stuff you are doing doesn't really make sense), but I'm quite qure that there is no driver bug. My guess is that you just screw up the state of a specific texture object, by calling that `ilutGLInit()` while it is still bound. It is totally unclear why the init function would want to do what it does - it would have partly made sense in OpenGL 1.0 from 1992, but not in any version after the invention of texture objects. This code is just broken.

Comment: I have added bit more comments to my original question. Maybe you can elaborate bit deeper on subject ?

Comment: There is not much I could elaborate on. Setting the texture filter to `GL_LINEAR` doesn't "corrupt" anything. It just sets the textture filter. And you can call it as many times you like. So the main questions remain - why is `ilutGLInit()` even trying to set a texture filte,r when it is meant to be called at a time when there are no textures to set the filter on? And why do you call it several times? And if you know that it modifies the texture filter, why do you call it while you still have a texture bound, allwoing to swith the filter to Linear, whily you obvousily want mipmapping?

Comment: Our rendering engine is rather complex, so I suspect there are some sort of improved texturing filters applied - I can see calls to ilutGLBindMipmaps ilutGLBindTexImage calls are happening in code.

Never mind what I'm trying to do here. Call you tell me how textures must be loaded using ilutGLInit after open gl is initialized also does not make textures to appear correctly. Is there some function I'm missing - maybe ilutGLInit must be done after ilutGLBindMipmaps / ilutGLBindTexImage function calls ?